# $f$ is continuous iff it is locally bounded in $\mathbb R$ .

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ have  closed graph.Then $f$ is continuous iff $f$ is locally bounded.

Here closed graph means the set $\{(x,f(x):x\in \mathbb R\}$ is closed.

I  have done one part ,i.e. if $f$ is continuous then it is locally bounded but at  the converse part I'm stuck.

Please someone help..

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)|<2M$ where $M$ is the bound, can you continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded on $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ then it is alson bounded on $[a-\frac\epsilon2,a+\frac\epsilon2]$. Then the graph of $f$ restricted to $[a-\frac\epsilon2,a+\frac\epsilon2]$ is closed and bounded, hence compact. Thus any sequence $(x_n,f(x_n))$ with $x_n\to a$ (and $|x_n-a|<\frac\epsilon 2$) must have a converging subsequence ...

Comment: Let the convergent subsequence be $(x_{r_n},f(x_{r_n}))$ then we have to show that this converges to $(a,f(a)),$ right? but why $f(x_{r_n})$ converges to f(a)?